# How to calculate negative log base ten in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf`. I want to calculate `-log base 10` for all the values in `mydf$colx`.

Comment: Using something like `-log10()`?

Comment: @Pascal yes, what would be the format in R?

Comment: `-log10(100)` gives `-2`...

Comment: Or using the general form: `-log(100, 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either the `log10(x)` function or the general form `log(x, base)`:

```
-log10(100)
# [1] -2

log10(100) * -1
# [1] -2

-log(100, base = 10)
# [1] -2

log(100, base = 10) * -1
# [1] -2
```